# angular.js route not found reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Chrome console Im getting :

```
route props: Object {history: Object, location: Object, params: Object, route: Object, routeParams: Object…} bundle.js:1
 route not found, reloading...
```

And it goes into a loop of reloading. This is not happening in Firefox. Its using angular.js although Im not 100% sure since Im new to angular.I have included https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js in my page but still not working.  What could be the problem ? What should I be looking for?